# Asterisk - sip phone has no sound

Tags: asterisk

I have an asterisk server v 11.7 on an aws ec2 ubuntu 14.04 image but can't get any sound from a sip phone (either zoiper or linphone) over OpenVPN. I have tried both use DTMF SIP INFO and RFC2833 but neither works. The phones both play their default sounds ok. The asterisk server answers ok and extensions.conf is working fine in the CLI. I also have twilio configured and dialling in with skype works fine.

Here is my sip.conf

```
[general]
context=public
allowoverlap=no
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
tcpenable=no
transport=udp
localnet=10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
externip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
nat=force_rport,comedia
preferred_codec_only=yes
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
sipdebug=yes

[friends_internal](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
dtmfmode=auto
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0

[markhorrocks](friends_internal)
secret=not-telling
```

Here is iptables [redacted]

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5222 -m comment --comment "055 asterisk-jingle-tcp-5222" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5223 -m comment --comment "055 asterisk-jingle-tcp-5223" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 5222 -m comment --comment "055 asterisk-jingle-udp-5222" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 5223 -m comment --comment "055 asterisk-jingle-udp-5223" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5060 -m comment --comment "055 asterisk-sip-tcp-5060" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5061 -m comment --comment "055 asterisk-sip-tcp-5061" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 5060 -m comment --comment "055 asterisk-sip-udp-5060" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 5061 -m comment --comment "055 asterisk-sip-udp-5061" -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set Zoiper Settings -> Advanced, Use rport media. Finally it worked.

Comment: you are a life saver